# how can i implement numbering for markers in mapview?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using `MapView` in my application, Which contains several markers of same user at different locations. How can i give numbers to each incoming markers in order to identify the user path in which he moves ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend OverlayItem by your own class and store all the information inside.

```
MyOverlayItem<Data> myMarker = new MyOverlayItem<Data>(geoPoint, "", "");
myMarker.setID(0);
```

Also yoo need to extend `ItemizedOverlay` and bring markers to your `MyOverlayMarker`

Comment: I would like to give integer values to each marker in increasing order  which give a clear idea i hope.

Comment: You can add static variable to your class and use it as global counter

Comment: I just wanted to show this marker along with this integer value in the mapview..Is it possible ?